# How to debug ld.so.1: fatal: relocation error:?

Tags: unix, solaris

I've been messing around on a Solaris box, installing precompiled lib/programs from the repos by extracting them and placing them in my home dir.
It seems everything I've tried so far works, except for irssi.
I get the following error:

```
 $ ~/bin/irssi                                                                                                                                                                    
 ld.so.1: irssi: fatal: relocation error: file /export/home0/leem2/bin/irssi: symbol boot_DynaLoader: referenced symbol not found
 Killed
```

Any ideas on how to debug this?

EDIT:
I have run:

```
 $ ldd /export/home0/leem2/bin/irssi
```

and it has no missing libs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you're missing a symbol yet have all your libs, you probably have a version issue - the app depends on a newer version of the library (with the symbol) than what you have.

However, this seems to be strictly a [perl-embed issue](http://www.nntp.perl.org/group/perl.perl5.porters/2004/01/msg86931.html).

Comment: installing a newer version of perl and making sure the path variables point to the right one fixed it